# Parse/Extract information from text template

Tags: c#, parsing, templates

i need to extract information from incoming (e.g. xml) data based on a given template.
The template may be XML or plain text (comma separated). For each type of message there exists a template, e.g.

```
<SomeMessage>
    <Id>$id</Id>
    <Position>
        <X>$posX</X>
        <Y>$posY</Y>
        <Z>$posZ</Z>
    </Position>
</SomeMessage>
```

The incoming data for example is:

```
<SomeMessage>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Position>
        <X>0.5f</X>
        <Y>1.0f</Y>
        <Z>0.0f</Z>
    </Position>
</SomeMessage>
```

Now i need to extract information about $id, $posX, etc.

```
Parser p = new Parser(templateString);
int id = p.Extract("id", incomingString);
float posx = p.Extract("posX", incomingString);
```

I need something like the difference of incomingData and template and then extract the information at the appropiate position. Because there exist several tempaltes which contain different information and may be extended in the future i am looking for a general  approach.

The template in this case may also be

```
$id,$posX,$posY,$posZ
```

and the incoming data would be then

```
1,0.5f,1.0f,0.0f
```

The latter case may be eaiser to parse, but i need a solution which is able the handle both (xml template as well as non xml).

Comment: [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is probably the best API for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a parsing class having a property for each field:

```
class Parser
{
    public string PositionX { get; set; }
    public string PositionY { get; set; }
    public string PositionZ { get; set; }

    public Parser(XmlNode item)
    {
        this.PositionX = GetNodeValue(item, "Position/X");
        this.PositionY = GetNodeValue(item, "Position/X/Y");
        this.PositionZ = GetNodeValue(item, "Position/X/Y/Z");
    }
}
```

I can supply a routine that can generate such parsing classes from sample xml if your interested, when arrays do not concern. GetNodeValue is a method that uses an xpath query and returns the value for the xpath (basicly XmlNode.SelectSingleNode with some added parsing added to it).

Comment: Thanks, but it should be more flexible. The problem is, the XML template may change (e.g. "Position" will change to" "Pos" or some children will be added to "Position"). Also the template format must not be XML based, so i am looking for a more generic solution, e.g. using regex/string matching functions.

Comment: This method was setup to create classes that can be used in an application so that the structure of the incomming object is defined. When the structure is changing regularly, i would suggest linq to xml, like oded suggested.

Comment: Yes, it is or may change in future. I am not sure how to use linq to xml to extract information from an input string based on a template and variable definition, maybe someone has an example.

Comment: Would it be an option to work with a method (incorporated in an application) that generates the parsing class, and when the message changes, to regenerate the parsing class?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a good idea to use a Interface and 2 different templates for each occasion. Note that the returned Message is not completed but it gives you an idea. With the static `XElement.Parse` you can parse well formed XML strings for easier usage.

```
public interface IParser
{
    Message Parse(String Payload);
}
 // Position Class
 public class Position
 {
 public int X { get; private set; }
 public int Y { get; private set; }
 public int Z { get; private set; }
 public Position(int X, int Y, int Z)
 {
  this.X = X;
  this.Y = Y;
  this.Z = Z;
 }
}
// Message Class 
public class Message
{
 public String ID { get; private set; }
 public Position Position { get; private set; }
 public Message(String ID, Position Position)
 {
   this.ID = ID;
   this.Position = Position;
 }
}
 // Parser Class
 public class XMLParser : IParser
{
 public Message Parse(string Payload)
 {
  var result = XElement.Parse(Payload);
  return new Message(result.Elements().ElementAt(0).Value, new Position(X,Y,Z);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each template create a parser definition file of the format:

Parser Type (XML or CSV)

Variable1, path

variable2, path

etc

for xml path might be someMessage,Position,x.

for csv you might forget the path and just list the variables in order.

Then when you read in your template file your pick up the parser type and the path to each of the variables. If you have a lot of hierarchical information then you'll have to apply a bit of imagination to this but it should be fine for the simple case you've given.

For anything over CSV you will probably have to use a parser, but XML/XPATH is pretty simple to find the basics for.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

class TemplateParse {
    XmlDocument xdoc;

    string GetPath(XmlNode node, string val, string path){
        if(node.HasChildNodes){
            if(node.ChildNodes.Count == 1 && node.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                return (node.FirstChild.Value == val) ? path + "/" + node.Name : String.Empty;
            foreach(XmlNode cnode in node.ChildNodes){
                if(cnode.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;
                string result = GetPath(cnode, val, path + "/" + node.Name);
                if(result != String.Empty) return result;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    public TemplateParse(string templateXml){
        xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(templateXml);
    }
    public string Extract(string valName, string data){
        string xpath =  GetPath((XmlNode)xdoc.DocumentElement, "$" + valName, "/");
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(data);
        return  doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
//      var value = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
//      var retType = typeof(T);
//      return (T)retType.InvokeMember("Parse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new []{value});
    }
}

class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string templateString = File.ReadAllText(@".\template.xml");
        string incomingString = File.ReadAllText(@".\data.xml");

        var p = new TemplateParse(templateString);

        string[] names = new [] { "id", "posX", "posY", "posZ" };
        foreach(var name in names){
            var value = p.Extract(name, incomingString);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id:1
posX:0.5f
posY:1.0f
posZ:0.0f
```